# Chemical potential vs Electrostatic potential in semiconductors

Tags: electrons, potential-energy, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, fermi-energy

In Semiconductor Physics, the bottom of conduction band $E_C$ is treated as the electrostatic potential. This energy level is typically used to express the carrier concentration in terms of the electrostatic potential and then is used in combination with Poisson's equation to obtain the potential distribution throughout a pn-junction.

**But how can $E_C$ correspond to a potential energy of en electron?**

It makes sence that the electron having energy less than $E_C$ is bound to an atom and so is immobile. Then it can gain sufficient kinetic energy to leave to the conduction band.

But I see no reason why the electrons cannot have potential energy less than $E_C$. In fact, any energy less than $E_C$ is a valid potential energy of an electron in a semiconductor. Yet the books state with no justification that $E_C$ corresponds to potential energy and move on.

Also, the Fermi level or *chemical potential* is basically the average energy per particle in a system. It consists of electrostatic potential, gravitational potential and other interactions. **How come the Fermi level is often lower than $E_C$ then, if $E_C$ is only the electrostatic potential?**

Comment: If there are no states to occupy between the top of the valence band and the bottom of the conduction band, then no, an electron cannot have an energy in between - there is no state for it to occupy. It would be like saying you want the electron in a hydrogen atom to have an energy partway between the ground state and the first excited state - it can't happen.

Comment: But bound electrons can be at any energy in the valence band

Comment: Yes, there are a large number of states at various energies in the valence band. And nearly all are occupied by electrons.

Comment: And Poisson's equation deals with electrostatic potential at any point, not only with the potential of free electrons

Comment: @JonCuster so this means that valence electrons do not have PE equal to $E_C$? How can we use $PE = E_C$ in Poisson's equation then to determine potential and $E$ field distribution everywhere in the system?

Comment: I suspect more that the bottom of the conduction band was selected as the reference energy.

Comment: No, books explicitly state it is the potential energy itself and typically use $E_F$ or $0$ as reference

Comment: In addition, if I understand correctly, the electron is initially at some $PE <= E_V$. Then it can gain kinetic energy to move over to the conduction band. If the energy needed to move to conduction band can only be  gained due to kinetic component, then the potential energy of free electrons should be $E_V$

Comment: Where are you even getting the PE from? This is not a potential energy like gravitational potential energy is. You have way too many misconceptions to meaningfully begin helping you with. In a material that has a band gap, the electrons fill up the orbitals until the top of the valence band, $E_V$. i.e. there are many electrons with many different amounts of energy, all the way up to there. Then there is no electrons with energies in between $E_V$ and $E_C$. The only physically sensible definition of $E_F$ is the $\lim T\to0$ of $\mu$, and there lies the electrostatic bits, needing stat therm

Comment: I understand that no electron can be in band gap. I get PE from charges around. From nuclei in particular

Comment: And I had no objection to the definition of $E_F$. But $\mu$ is still the chemical potential

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I hopefully resolved the confusion by comments above. I do understand what I'm talking about and this is clearly not a stupid question, as electostatic potential in a semiconductor obviously varies a lot due to the presence of so many charges. This is why I see no reason to assume that the potential corresponds simply to $E_C$. However, books like Sze and many many others just state this with no explanation whatsoever. I would greatly appreciate your help with this

Comment: To the part about how can $E_F$ be less than the electostatic potential I figure that this is because the chemical potential is the average potential per particle

Comment: I am not saying you are asking a stupid question. I am indirectly asking which book you are using and telling you to burn it. If you are talking about the electrostatic potential due to the ions, that is the V in the Hamiltonian, and is a legitimate PE. But the chemical potential = electrochemical potential $\mu$ is NOT a PE of the same type. This latter type is a thermodynamic potential, and has to be a flat constant, even across junctions, to establish thermal equilibrium. The only sensible definition is $E_F=\lim_{T\to0}\mu$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Chemical potential is defined as adding $dN$ particles to the system gives it the energy $\mu dN$. And my question is no longer focused around it, as I already have an understanding of that part. I'm interested in the electrostatic potential and how to relate is to some band parameters in order to express the carrier concentration in terms of this potential, plug them into the Poisson's equation and then obtain he actual charge and $E$ field profile of the depletion region

Comment: $V\to$ bands; nobody knows how to work backwards. And I just told you that $\mu$ will pick up electrostatic contribution too. It is very horrible. You cannot just ignore one of them.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Do you then state that saying $E_C$ corresponds to potential energy, and so $\varphi = \frac{E_C}{q}$ is wrong? I think this is nonsence, but about a dozen famous books say this, so I asked just to be safe. And I totally agree with your last 3 sentences, however, I don't see what you are hinting at with them

Comment: I will definitely disagree with characterising the energy level of the lowest conduction band energy state $E_C$ as a potential energy. That energy can be shifted; only things like band gaps, which is a subtraction of two such energies, can be physically meaningful, and that is still not a form of potential energy. I do not know what famous books you are using. I stick to really proper and famous books, albeit maybe a little old. The horribly written Kittel, the nicer Ashcroft and Mermin, and modern versions thereof.